# cakephp find list

Tags: cakephp

Can anybody please tell me how to query list.

Is this ok ?

```
$part1Achiveds = $this->Part2Achived->Part1Achived->ProComp->find('list',array('conditions='=>array('ProComp.id=Part2Achiveds.pro_comp_id')));
```

Comment: You'll get an SQL error with that query, something along the line "unknown Part2Achiveds.pro_comp_id"

Answer (score 0):

Key => value is preferred over what your are doing:

```
$part1Achiveds = $this->Part2Achived->Part1Achived->ProComp->find('list',array(
    'conditions='=>array(
        // Model.field => Model.field instead of Model.field = Model.field
        $this->ProComp->alias.'id' => $this->Part2Achived->alias.'.pro_comp_id'
    )
));
```

You should also review your recursiveness and your associations. Since:

Part2Achived->Part1Achived->ProComp

ProComp is 2 recursiveness-distances away from Part2Achived, so set recursive to 2 or use Containable.